# Native IDE Call Stack window became always empty on crash

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney

I did something in IDE options, and after some time this window became always empty. Does anybody knows what's the deal?

To test I do something simple like this

```
app.log('crash test '+inttostr(1 div JvTrayIcon1.IconIndex));
```

...and it rises, asks me to break, I do break, and.. there is nothing in Call Stack. But I remember it worked, and worked amazingly fine...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it! highly likely it is just IDE bug. Just **do not detach this window**. Return it back to main desktop flow. And it will work again.

[image]